# Где посмотреть журнал ошибок профилировщика в Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, профилирование

Есть приложение ASP NET Core. Требуется профилирование. IIS Express профилирование не поддерживает, поэтому запускаю на Kestrel.

Когда запускаю профилирование, получаю вот такое сообщение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и профилирование сразу останавливается. 
Где прочитать эти самые журналы, чтобы понять в чем дело? 
Ну или может кто навскидку скажет как это исправить?